# How to get local time in php?

Tags: php

I am trying to get the local time using php. I wrote two different versions, but they both give the wrong time

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$now = new DateTime();
echo $now->getTimestamp();
```

Another way

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New York');
echo strtotime("now")."<br/>";;
$now = new DateTime();
echo $now->getTimestamp();
```

In both cases I get the time 4 fours ahead of my local time. There is any other way to get the local time?

Comment: Is `America/New York` your local timezone? Do they both return the same value?

Comment: @esqew yes they both return the same time

Comment: Better to get the date/time from Mysql or JS.

Comment: @SureshKamrushi How'd you figure that?

Comment: @LeonardChallis yes my computer has the local time right

Comment: @SureshKamrushi How would you do that?

Comment: You're retrieving the timestamp. Timestamp is ALWAYS UTC. In other words, you will always, and I mean **always** get the UTC time when you call `getTimestamp()`.

Comment: N.B. is correct. Instead of printing a UNIX timestamp, printing `$now->format(DateTime::W3C)` would give you a more complete picture.

Comment: @Alexander: in Mysql use function CURDATE()

Comment: @N.B. you totally right. How would you get the local time?

Comment: The actual question that needs answering is this: what do you mean by local time?  I live in the UK, my "local" time is 16:24 which is going to be different to yours.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`DateTime::getTimestamp()` returns unix timestamp. That number is always UTC. What you want is format the date according to your time zone.

```
$dt = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));

echo $dt->format('m/d/Y, H:i:s');
```

Or use a different date format, according to what you need.

Also, you can use DateTime library for all your date needs. No need to change server's default timezone every time you want to fetch the date.

Comment: Thank you, I have another question. Once I get the local time, there is anyway I can convert that time to unix time?

Comment: What do you mean when you say unix time? When we talk about unix time, that means the timestamp - which brings us back to the start - you get number of seconds since 1970, which is in UTC.

Comment: As N.B. says though the above only works for dates after 1970 ;)

Comment: I am working in a project where we need to compare local time with the time that is stored in my database. I thought it would be easier to use unix timestamp. But it won't work because it would always be hours ahead of the real time.

Comment: Your best bet would be to ignore local time entirely and just stick with UTC time within your code.  If you ever need to display it you can use the DateTimeZone to format it for "human eyes".  The DateTime object does have a ->diff method too

Answer (score 12):

Simply use function  date_default_timezone_set(). Here is example:

```
<?php 
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Dhaka");
echo date('d-m-Y h:i:s A');
?>
```

Hope it will help,
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use javascript because you want the value of time from the client. PHP is a server-side language that evaluates on the server and sends results to the client. So if you try to pull a date/time using a PHP function, it's going to pull the date from the server, which is not always in the client's timezone.

You can do this in a javascript function and then reference the value in the display.

var thisDateTime = new Date();

Comment: +1. I'm not entirely sure why this has been down voted. This is a great way to give the users a local time AND correctly format data with Date::toLocaleString().

Comment: But if the server knows where (say) a retail store is, the server can calculate the time in the time zone of that location.

Comment: js is a problem. date and time posted on database will be server date not the client computer time

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use timezone you can use this mix of windows and php commands:

```
<?php 
  $D = exec('date /T');
  $T = exec('time /T');
  $DT = strtotime(str_replace("/","-",$D." ".$T));
  echo(date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$DT));
?>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I don't know why this answer was downvoted even when it's a valid answer.

Comment: Is good trick, but any times for any locales dont work. But is a good trick. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering why nobody has mentioned `localtime(time());` in PHP with indexed key array result or `localtime(time(), true);` with associative key array result.

Comment: This still needs date_default_timezone_set( timezonestring )

Answer (score 0):

For the record, I found the only solution to read the real hour of the machine is to read the information outside of PHP (javascript, shell or other processes).  Why?

For example, let's say we have an hour based in daily-saving.  What if the timezone of the OS (Windows in my case) is not in sync with the timezone of PHP, I mean, it could be calculated differently.  Or maybe the machine is using a different hour and it is ignoring the daily-saving hour.

Right now, my zone is UTC -4 Santiago 9:35 pm (with daily saving). However, PHP considers as 10:35 PM (using localtime,time,date and DateTime).

Answer (score 0):

If anyone here wanted to get the local time according to the user's timezone (dynamically), then you can consider the following code:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$ipInfo = file_get_contents('http://ip-api.com/json/' . $ip);
$ipInfo = json_decode($ipInfo);
$timezone = $ipInfo->timezone ?? "UTC";

$dt = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone($timezone));
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

The above code will get the user's local timezone and print the time according to that.

If you wanted to test the above code on your localhost then make sure to hard code your IP address there because the API can't provide you the timezone based on your local address (127.0.0.1), but the above code works fine on the
live server.

For Localhost, do:

```
$ip = '-------'; //your IP address
```

Answer (score -1):

You can solve this problem by using **localtime()** function or through **date_default_timezone_set()** function.

Learn more about the localtime() function reffer:
 http://php.net/manual/en/function.localtime.php

or

Learn more about the date_default_timezone_set() function reffer http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

i think this must help you..