# how to track my local time in php

Tags: php, localtime

i m trying to keep track when i m signed in and when i signout..i m creating a online attendence system. and i wrote these codes to track..but it is not keeping track in my local time..when i m singing in at 10am it is showing signed in at 4pm..what should i do?

```
    $result = $_GET["result"];

    $date = date('Y-m-d');
    $day = date('l');
    $min = date('i');
    $hour = date('H');

    $min = $min - 5;
    if($min<0){ $hour=$hour-1; $min=$min+60;}
    $time = $hour.":".$min;
    $settime = $time;
    $settime1 = date('H:i');
?>
<form name="form1" method="post" action= "" >
  <table width="760" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">    
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="4" rowspan="4" valign="top"><br>    
        <table width="256" border="1" bordercolor="#CCCCCC">
            <tr> 
              <th width="82" scope="col"><div align="center">User Name </div></th>
              <th width="82" scope="col">Time Req. </th>
              <th width="78" scope="col">Time Spent </th>
            </tr>
            <?php
                $result = $_GET["result"];

                $date = date('Y-m-d');
                $day = date('l');
                $min = date('i');
                $hour = date('H');

                $min = $min - 5;
                if($min < 0){ 
                    $hour=$hour-1; $min=$min+60;
                }
                $time = $hour.":".$min;
                $settime = $time;
                $settime1 = date('H:i');

                $query = "select * from presence where uid=".$uid." and date='".$date."'";
                $recordset = mysql_query($query);
                while($record = mysql_fetch_array($recordset)){
                  $count = 1;
                  //echo "<td>Today you timed in at:- ",$record["timein"],"</td></tr><br></table>";
                  //$lasttimeout = $record["timeout"];
                }
                if($count != 1) {
                    $query2 = "insert into presence(timein, timeout, date, uid, pday) 
                    values('$settime', '$settime1', '$date', $uid, '$day')";
                    $af = mysql_query($query2);
                    //echo "<td>Today you timed in at:- ",$settime,"</td></tr><br></table>";
                    $lasttimeout = date('H:i');
                }

                //echo "<table><tr><td>Today you last timed out at:- ",$lasttimeout," 
                //</td></tr></table>";
                $array1 = array();
                $array2 = array();
                $array3 = array();
                $array4 = array();
                $userid = array();
                $great = 0; 

                function calculate($timein, $timeout) {
                    $timespentin = split(":",$timein,3);
                    $timespentout = split(":",$timeout,3);
                    //print_r($timespentin);
                    //print_r($timespentout);
                    $t1 = $timespentin[0]*60 + $timespentin[1];
                    $t2 = $timespentout[0]*60 + $timespentout[1];
                    $timespent = round(($t2 - $t1)/60,2);
                    //echo $timespent;
                    return $timespent;
                 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  date_default_timezone_set function

```
 date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta");

 $login_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP is install on server and default `UTC` timezone, you will need to change timezone according your local timezone, place `date_default_timezone_set("time_zone");` function at top of script

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Bangkok");
echo date_default_timezone_get();
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
?>
```

[TIMEZONE list](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

Answer (score 0):

Which timezone are you on ? you should set the default timezone using

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
```

This line should go at the top of the file, before you use `date` function.
Read more on [setting default timezone](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) and [timezone regions](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');//set your time zone 

echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');// get the date
```

see set sefault time Zone here:http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php
and time zones here:http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime::getTimestamp()` returns unix timestamp. That number is always UTC. What you want is format the date according to your time zone.

```
$dt = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));

echo $dt->format('m/d/Y, H:i:s');
```

Or use a different date format, according to what you need.

Also, you can use DateTime library for all your date needs. No need to change server's default timezone every time you want to fetch the date.

Read [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) for more info

Source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/24914436/1877909