# Parse a UTC date, output local datetime

Tags: php, datetime, timezone, utc, strtotime

I have already read [How to get local time in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24914227/how-to-get-local-time-in-php) and similar questions, but here I want to do the contrary:

**With a given datetime in UTC (e.g. `2021-03-31 23:45:00`), how to output the date in local timezone?**

```
$dt = new DateTime("2021-03-31 23:45:00");  // parse the UTC datetime
echo $dt->format('m/d/Y, H:i:s');
```

In Europe/Paris timezone, it should output `2021-04-01 01:45:00`, but here it sill outputs `2021-03-31 23:45:00`. How to fix this?

I also tried with `strtotime` with a similar result; I also tried with:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$dt = new DateTime("2021-03-31 23:46:14");
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');
echo $dt->format('m/d/Y, H:i:s');
```

without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the timezone of the date (using [`DateTime::setTimeZone()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php)), not the default timezone:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$dt = new DateTime("2021-03-31 23:46:14");
$dt->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone("Europe/paris")); // change date timezone
echo $dt->format('m/d/Y, H:i:s');
```

Output:

```
04/01/2021, 01:46:14
```

Changing the default timezone affects the `new DateTime()`, not the `format()` result.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it possible to remove the `date_default_timezone` (because it might affect other function using dates in the rest of the code), and set UTC inside `new DateTime` instead?

Comment: Yes, using the second parameter of the constructor : https://3v4l.org/9bM5P

Answer (score 1):

This can also be easily solved with date and strtotime:

```
//The following line is only required if the server has a different time zone.
//date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');

$utcDate = "2021-03-31 23:45:00";

echo date('m/d/Y, H:i:s',strtotime($utcDate.' UTC'));
```

Output:

```
04/01/2021, 01:45:00
```